# Is it ok to write MySQL queries on Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Referring Laravel tutorials I started to create Laravel application, I saw some tutors wrote MySQL queries **on Controller**

eg:

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->user_name = $input['user_name'];
    $user->email = $input['email'];
    $user->password = $input['password'];
    $user->phone = $input['phone'];
    $user->mobile = $input['mobile'];
    $user->address = $input['address'];
    $user->save();
```

eg 2:

```
$data['count'] = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_count FROM users WHERE notification='1'");
```

**Is it ok to write these all queries on Laravel Controller?** Please advice me

Comment: usually not. queries belong to your database-interaction layer (storage, model, whatever…). p.s. this question is offtopic here and fits https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ much better

Comment: Why don't you use the [querybuilder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)?

Answer (score 0):

From an MVC standpoint, it goes against the standard.
However, you could put queries in controllers. When I have written queries in the past, I usually keep simple ones in the controllers and complex ones in the models. It is really up to you. 
You can create a controller function that does nothing but saves to the model.

```
// Controller
class UserController extends BaseController
{

    function afterFormGetsSubmitted(){
        $formData = Input::get();
        saveToModel($formData);

        /*
            Do other stuff
        */
    }

    function saveToModel($input){
        $user = new User();
        $user->user_name = $input['user_name'];
        $user->email = $input['email'];
        $user->password = $input['password'];
        $user->phone = $input['phone'];
        $user->mobile = $input['mobile'];
        $user->address = $input['address'];
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

Here is a link to someone who was asking about SQL queries and controllers:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143248/strategies-for-avoiding-sql-in-your-controllers-or-how-many-methods-should-i